# How to add custom column in category grid of custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to add the category ID to the category list table for a custom post type using `manage_{$taxonomy}_custom_column`, and I found out that the function is now deprecated.

The filter is now red on the following page with no usage information available:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column

And the following page says the filter is now deprecated, with no followup information since version 3:
http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/manage_{$taxonomy}_custom_column

I came across this solution on github, but it doesn't work: https://gist.github.com/maxfenton/593473788c2259209694

I've not found any solution that serves as a replacement for `manage_{$taxonomy}_custom_column`. Does anyone have any idea how to go about adding a category ID column in the category grid view?

Here is a screenshot showing where I want to add the ID:

[image]

Comment: Where does it say that it's deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
// To show the column header
function custom_column_header( $columns ){
  $columns['header_name'] = 'Header Name for Display'; 
  return $columns;
}

add_filter( "manage_edit-(your-texanomy)_columns", 'custom_column_header', 10);

// To show the column value
function custom_column_content( $value, $column_name, $tax_id ){
   return $tax_id ;
}
add_action( "manage_(your-texanomy)_custom_column", 'custom_column_content', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you for posting Shravan, but `manage_{$taxonomy}_custom_column` is deprecated. This is the reason for my post.

Comment: Opps, but it's working fine with my latest wordpress(4.4.2) without any warning.

Comment: I just put your code in and it does work! The difference between your code and what I had been using is the `10, 3` at the end. What's that for? Priority?

Comment: As the variable name it show the current texanomy id.

Answer (score 1):

Edited the code:

```
add_filter('manage_edit-{custom_post_type}_columns', 'mytheme_categoy_id_column', 10, 2);

if (!function_exists('mytheme_categoy_id_column')) {
    function mytheme_categoy_id_column($cat_columns){
        $cat_columns['cat_id'] = esc_html__('Category ID', 'mytheme');
        return $cat_columns;
    }
}

add_filter ('manage_{custom_post_type}_custom_column', 'mytheme_custom_column_content', 10,3);

if (!function_exists('mytheme_custom_column_content')) {
    function mytheme_custom_column_content($deprecated, $column_name, $term_id){
        if ($column_name == 'cat_id') {
            return $term_id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a solution dingo, but I need help with the taxonomy grid, not specifically custom post type grid. http://snag.gy/JGF7g.jpg

Comment: Thank you dingo. I gave you an up vote, but Shravan had posted a solution that works for me just before you updated your solution. I at the very least wanted to up vote you for your answer. I'm sure others will find it helpful too. Thank you!