# How do I add custom fields to the categories in Woocommerce?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I have a woocommerce site that groups products within categories and displays them on the initial shop page.

I want to add custom fields to the categories.

Theory: On the home page is a search form, the user types in their postcode and the categories with the matching postcode details (which will be specified within the custom fields) are displayed. 
I don't need the custom fields to show on the shop page, I just need to be able to apply the matching postcodes in the backend.

Please does anyone know how I can do this?

I've been working on it for ages and can't seem to find a solution. 
A huge thank you any answers or suggestions in advance. 
P.S: I don't want to use a plugin, just php/html/javascript (& other code) please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add custom column in category grid of custom post type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36331168/how-to-add-custom-column-in-category-grid-of-custom-post-type)

Comment: http://www.wpmusketeer.com/add-a-wysiwyg-field-to-woocommerce-product-category-page/

This will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code in your themes function.php to create custom field on your product categories taxonomy.

```
// Add term page
function custom_product_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field() {
    // this will add the custom meta field to the add new term page
    ?>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="term_meta[custom_term_meta]"><?php _e( 'Postalcode', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" id="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" value="">
        <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter a value for this field','my-text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php
}
add_action( 'product_cat_add_form_fields', 'custom_product_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field', 10, 2 );
// Edit term page
function custom_product_taxonomy_edit_meta_field($term) {

    // put the term ID into a variable
    $t_id = $term->term_id;

    // retrieve the existing value(s) for this meta field. This returns an array
    $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" ); ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="term_meta[custom_term_meta]"><?php _e( 'Postalcode', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" id="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $term_meta['custom_term_meta'] ) ? esc_attr( $term_meta['custom_term_meta'] ) : ''; ?>">
            <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter a value for this field','my-text-domain' ); ?></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
add_action( 'product_cat_edit_form_fields', 'custom_product_taxonomy_edit_meta_field', 10, 2 );
// Save extra taxonomy fields callback function.
function save_taxonomy_custom_meta( $term_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['term_meta'] ) ) {
        $t_id = $term_id;
        $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );
        $cat_keys = array_keys( $_POST['term_meta'] );
        foreach ( $cat_keys as $key ) {
            if ( isset ( $_POST['term_meta'][$key] ) ) {
                $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['term_meta'][$key];
            }
        }
        // Save the option array.
        update_option( "taxonomy_$t_id", $term_meta );
    }
}  
add_action( 'edited_product_cat', 'save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );  
add_action( 'create_product_cat', 'save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );
```

you can save this custom field along with categories. you can used this custom field for your filtration.

Comment: I don't know what's going on but none of these suggestions are working.

Comment: you can create custom field (postalcode) with this code inside woocommerce product categories taxonomy.

Comment: By literally doing a copy & paste to my functions.php file?

Comment: Of course. But still no luck unfortunately :( This does work if I'm using a local host right?

Comment: I just applied this code inside my localhost and this code create postalcode field inside categories taxonomy. here is screenshot for getting more reference. http://screencast.com/t/irMBLoVoXNPa

Comment: AHHHH! I completely missed it! I see what you mean! And it's worked PERFECTLY. Thank you sooooo mcuh!

Comment: Quick question: is there a way to add this extra field so that it also shows on the front end underneath the category name?

Comment: Yes it is possible but you have to write some code for it. As default it not displaying our custom flied.

Comment: Could you help me with how to do this please?