# Additional image field in WooCommerce category

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, woocommerce, categories

With help i've made custom field on WooCommerce's category, but i want to make it media field (to pick cover image and upload directly from form).

I'm using "[How do I add custom fields to the categories in Woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37182816/11987538)"

```php
// Add term page
function custom_product_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field() {
    // this will add the custom meta field to the add new term page
    ?>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="term_meta[category_cover]"><?php _e( 'Category Cover', 'category-cover' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="term_meta[category_cover]" id="term_meta[category_cover]" value="">
        <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter a value for this field','category-cover' ); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php
}
add_action( 'product_cat_add_form_fields', 'custom_product_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field', 10, 2 );
// Edit term page
function custom_product_taxonomy_edit_meta_field($term) {

    // put the term ID into a variable
    $t_id = $term->term_id;

    // retrieve the existing value(s) for this meta field. This returns an array
    $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" ); ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="term_meta[category_cover]"><?php _e( 'Category Cover', 'category-cover' ); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="term_meta[category_cover]" id="term_meta[category_cover]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $term_meta['category_cover'] ) ? esc_attr( $term_meta['category_cover'] ) : ''; ?>">
            <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter an URL for category cover','category-cover' ); ?></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
add_action( 'product_cat_edit_form_fields', 'custom_product_taxonomy_edit_meta_field', 10, 2 );
// Save extra taxonomy fields callback function.
function save_taxonomy_custom_meta( $term_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['term_meta'] ) ) {
        $t_id = $term_id;
        $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );
        $cat_keys = array_keys( $_POST['term_meta'] );
        foreach ( $cat_keys as $key ) {
            if ( isset ( $_POST['term_meta'][$key] ) ) {
                $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['term_meta'][$key];
            }
        }
        // Save the option array.
        update_option( "taxonomy_$t_id", $term_meta );
    }
}  
add_action( 'edited_product_cat', 'save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );  
add_action( 'create_product_cat', 'save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );
```

I dont know what should I tell more, but i will be really thankful for help me! :)

Comment: just to be clear, do you want to change the existing field you added to an media (image) upload field? where should the uploaded image eventually appear?

Comment: Yes! I need two images related to one category - logo (of category) and cover we see on category's page (own theme).